# Routing Functionality breaks after upgrading the angular version from 13 to 15.2.9

Tags: router, angular15, angular-router-events

I did the angular upgrade from 13 to 15.2.9 successfully with no error in cli. When i tried navigating from one tab to another the routing functionality breaks without throwing any error. On 1st click its not navigating to the tab but on 2nd click its navigating correctly. Please help to resolve the issue.